# Alternative for AWK use

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, mv

I'd love to have a more elegant solution for a mass rename of files, as shown below. Files were of format `DEV_XYZ_TIMESTAMP.dat` and we needed them as `T-XYZ-TIMESTAMP.dat`.
In the end, I copied them all (to be on the same side) into `renamed` folder:

```
ls -l *dat|awk '{system("cp " $10 " renamed/T-" substr($10, index($10, "_")+1))}'
```

So, first I listed all dat files, then picked up 10th column (file name) and executed a command using awk's *system* function. 
The command was essentially copying of original filename into *renamed* folder with new file name.
New file name was created by removing (awk *substring* function) prefix before (including) _ and adding "T-" prefix.

Effectively:

```
cp DEV_file.dat renamed/T-file.dat
```

Is there a way to use `cp` or `mv` together with some regex rules to achieve the same in a bit more elegant way?

Thx

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Awk is a tool for manipulating text. Shell is a tool for manipulating files/processes and sequencing calls to tools. You're trying to use awk to manipulate (rename) files so therefore you're using the wrong tool - just use shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
cpdir=renamed
for file in *dat; do
    newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s/[^_]*/T/" -e "y/_/-/")
    cp "$file" "$cpdir/$newfile"
done
```

The `sed` scripts transforms every non-underscore leading characters in a single T and then replaces every `_` with `-`. If `cpdir` is not sure to exist before execution, you can simply add `mkdir "$cpdir"` after first line.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this script:

```
for file in *.dat; do
   f="${file//_/-}"
   mv "$file" renamed/T-"${f#*-}"
done
```

[You must avoid parsing output of `ls` command.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: OK, I have to admit `f="${file//_/-}"` and `"${f#*-}"` syntax is a total new for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, but be sure to add `#!/bin/bash` shebang on the first line because if `sh` gets its hands on the script, it will complain.

Comment: @Quasímodo: Question is tagged as `bash` as well.

Comment: @hummingBird: `f="${file//_/-}"` replaces all `_` with `-` in `$file` and stores result in variable `f`. `"${f#*-}"` removes test until first `-` in `$f`.

Comment: @anubhava Sure, that is a totally valid answer, it was just a reminder for OP.

Comment: Thx both for your great answers. I accepted Quasimodo's for the clear fact it came in faster and it solved my problem.

Comment: Just to let you know I had posted my answer 6 minutes before accepted answer. Also in terms of efficiency it is always faster to avoid spawning subprocesses and calling external utilities if something can be entirely done in bash itself.  Quasimodo's forks 2 subprocesses: one for command substitution and two for pipe inside `$9...)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `rename` utilitity

`rename -E  "s/[^_]*/T/" -e "s/_/-/g" *dat`

Demo

```
$ls -1
ABC_DEF_TIMESTAMP.dat
DEV_XYZ_TIMESTAMP.dat
$rename -E  "s/[^_]*/T/" -e "s/_/-/g" * 
$ls -1
T-DEF-TIMESTAMP.dat
T-XYZ-TIMESTAMP.dat
$
```

Comment: Please note that there are different rename utilities. Depending on your system this command might have a different name, for instance `perl-rename` on arch. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/187122.